# Linking latitude and longitude data to zipcodes in Big Query

Tags: google-bigquery, geolocation, geospatial

I have the latitude and the longitude of some locations and I was wondering whether there is a way in BQ to link them to zipcodes. If it makes any difference, I am interested in Europe, and I need the zipcodes for Netherlands and Spain.

Answer (score 4):

If you have a database with the geometry of each zipcode:

```
WITH data AS (
  SELECT ST_GEOGPOINT(-122.4194, 37.7749) point
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT ST_GEOGPOINT(-74.0060, 40.7128) point
)
SELECT zip_code, city, county
FROM `bigquery-public-data.geo_us_boundaries.zip_codes` 
JOIN data
ON ST_WITHIN(point, zip_code_geom)
```

[image]

I used US data for this example - do you have a database of European zipcodes?

Comment: Perfect... saved me days. Thank you!